# Copiar id com 2 insert

Tags: php, mysqli, tabela-banco-de-dados, sql-insert

Bom eu tenho dois INSERT no mesmo arquivo, e eu quero que o id do primeiro INSERT(tabela1) também vá para o meu segundo INSERT(tabela2), eu realmente não sei como fazer, vou deixar tudo mais detalhado em baixo.

**INSERT 1 Anuncio**

```
$query = "INSERT INTO criar_anuncio (nome_funcionario, tipo_anuncio, cidade, cep, endereco, numero_casa, bairro, visibilidade, telefone, wpp, id_user_anun, data_cadastro) VALUES ('$post_funcionario', '$tipo_anuncio', '$cidade', '$cep', '$endereco', '$num_casa', '$bairro', '$visibilidade', '$telefone', '$wpp', '$id_user_anun', NOW())";
```

Até então um INSERT normal. Agora queria que o id que é auto incremento fosse para a minha segunda tabela.
**INSERT 2 Fotos dos Cômodos**

```
$query_comodos = "INSERT INTO `img_comodos`( `id_user`, `id_anuncio`, `img_file`) VALUES ('$id_user_anun', '$img_final_comodo')";
```

Bom, estou tentando trazer o id da minha tabela **Anuncio** para a minha tabela **Fotos Cômodos**, com cada id ocupando o campo **id_anuncio** na minha tabela 2.

**Aqui esta minha primeira tabela**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Aqui esta a minha segunda tabela, e eu quero ocupar o campo id_anuncio**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Dê uma olhada em `last insert id`, creio que seja o que precisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá!
Você pode recuperar o ID do insert usando a função `insert_id`

```
$query_comodos = "INSERT INTO `img_comodos`( `id_user`, `id_anuncio`, `img_file`) 
 VALUES ('$id_user_anun', '$img_final_comodo')";

$mysqli->query($query_comodos);
$id_anuncio = $mysqli->insert_id;
```